# ng-repeat, inside dynamic template used in directive, does not clone until after exiting directive's link function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am implementing custom directive of [jquery treetable](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/), I know there is [angular-treetable](https://github.com/GarrettHeel/angular-treetable) directive but it did not fit what I need.
I am using dynamic template that contain ng-repeat.

```
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="Row.html">
        <tr>
            <td data-id="{{node.id}}" ng-repeat="column in columns">{{node[column]}} </td>
        </tr>
    </script>
```

The problem is that I have access to cloned element only after digest cycle is over i.e. columns are created via compilation and linking then I need to call `element.treetable()` however it only works only if I set it in $timeout.
My understanding is it happens due to async nature of digest cycle (correct me if I am wrong).

What puzzles me is I log cloned rows/columns

```
var clonedElem = nodeLinkFn(nodeScope,function(cloned, scope)   {
                                                       //console.log(cloned);
                                                        elem.append(cloned); 
                                                      });
 console.log(clonedElem);
```

I see that cloning already happened however when I log entire element at the end of directive's link function
I do not see them and do not have access to them

For full example see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agcsi/9n0xeb3h/11/).

Is there any way to resolve it?